# HTML5 custom video controls

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want the substitute button to play the video on click. When I click the button nothing happens.. this is without the normal controls and I'm just testing this feature with a standard button but I'm not getting any response.

```
var func = function(){
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var but = document.getElementById('play-pause');
but.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if (video.paused == true) {
        video.play();
    }else{
        video.pause();
    }
});
}
func();
```

html

```
  <div id="vid">
<video id="video" width="420" controls>
<source src="images/tutorialUPLOAD.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<p> your browser does not support HTML5 video </p>
</video>



<div id="vidctrl">
<button type="button" id="play-pause">click here to start</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just made a js-fiddle and it works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/734ek/1/

Comment: wierd - not working on my chrome :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/zu6pK/light/

**HTML:-**

```
<video id="video" width="500" oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <source src="https://f9f9fce4f78470f7e248-0b04ae6868f3b76f0186ae4641e4c043.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/VidsToCloud.com-Upload-07-01-2013-104654117---What-is-HTML5--www.savevid.com-.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
<div id="Layer"></div>
<input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0">
<div class="clear"></div>
<img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minimal/22x22/status/audio-volume-high.png">
<input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
```

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //For adding play pause layer on top on the player
    $("#Layer").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: $("#video").offset().top,
        left: $("#video").offset().left,
        width: $("#video").outerWidth(),
        height: $("#video").outerHeight()
    });

    //Switching play/pause image on the player
    $("#Layer").on("click", function (e) {

        var myVideo = $("#video")[0];
        if (myVideo.paused) {
            myVideo.play();
            $(this).addClass("pause");
        } else {
            myVideo.pause();
            $(this).removeClass("pause");
        }
    });

    //Toggle behaviour for play/pause 
    $("#video").on("click", function (e) {
        var myVideo = $(this)[0];
        if (myVideo.paused) {
            myVideo.play();
        } else {
            myVideo.pause();
        }
    });

    //Showing/Hiding layer on top of the player
    $("#video").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
        $("#Layer").toggle();
    });

    //Volume bar to control video volume
    $("#volume-bar").on("change", function () {
        var myVideo = $("#video")[0];
        myVideo.volume = $(this).val();
    });

    //Seek bar to sync with the current playing video
    $("#video").on("timeupdate", function () {
        var myVideo = $(this)[0];
        var value = (100 / myVideo.duration) * myVideo.currentTime;
        $("#seek-bar").val(value);
    });

    //Seek bar drag to move the current playing video at the time.
    $("#seek-bar").on("mouseup", function () {
        var myVideo = $("#video")[0];

        var currentTime = $("#seek-bar").val() / (100 / myVideo.duration);
        myVideo.currentTime = currentTime;
    });

    $("#seek-bar").on("mousedown", function () {
        var myVideo = $("#video")[0];
        myVideo.pause();
    });

});
```

<kbd>[Reference](http://awizkid.tumblr.com/post/54346440345/simple-html5-video-player-with-custom-controls)</kbd>

Comment: any idea what was wrong with my original post? i dont understand why mine wont work but works fine in fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/734ek/1/

Comment: @Joe Try wrapping your code inside `document.ready` or `window.load` function

Comment: yea that worked - when I was using just pure js it was at top of doc but when i moved it below the code or put it inline with the html it was fine also jquery $(function(){ worked  - thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this code
**Javascript**

```
<script>
function playPause()
{       
    var myVideo=document.getElementById("template_35_vd_up"); 
            if (myVideo.paused) 
              {
                    myVideo.play();

              }
            else
            { 
              myVideo.pause();

            } 
} 
</script>
```

Html

```
<video width="650" height="440"  id="template_35_vd_up" controls="false" class="dragable"  style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:25px;" onclick="playPause()">

            <source src="upload_video/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">                           

            </source>
    </video>
                    <button onclick="playPause()" id='template35_playPouse'>Play/Pause</button>
```

Comment: Tried to edit but it's one character. Attribute "control" should be "controls".