# Detecting user dragging range type input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm creating a simple HTML5 audio player. I want the user to be able to drag the seek bar slider to whatever time they want, but with the code I currently have, when the timeupdate fires, the slider goes back to the original position (+1). How can I disable the seek bar from updating while user is dragging the slider?

```
$("#html5audio_seek").bind("change", function() {
    html5audio.currentTime = $(this).val();
    $("#html5audio_seek").attr("max", html5audio.duration);
});
html5audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',function (){
    curtime = parseInt(html5audio.currentTime, 10);
$("#html5audio_seek").attr("value", curtime);
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue when creating my own html mp3 reader. To fix this, I used the event `onmouseup`, and I checked the current value of the cursor and updated the time of the sound with this value.

Comment: @Zeratops Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344111/html5-custom-video-controls/20344487#20344487)?

Comment: Exactly what I had in my mind !

Comment: @Zeratops That works somewhat. User can't click on the seek bar anymore (to change the value), but dragging is smooth. Thanks!

Comment: I think if you set a "onclick" on your `input type='range'` you can do this too but not sure 100%, and you welcome !

Comment: @Zeratops Sadly that doesn't seem to work. I noticed that it does seek normally when the audio is not playing, and when user moves their mouse instead of simply clicking (when audio is playing).

Comment: If you may create a JSFiddle or Snippet code it would be way more easy to help because it begins to be quite complicated at this moment !

Comment: @Zeratops It does not work on JSFiddle, but you should get a clue on what it does. http://jsfiddle.net/ezLqbnj7/

Comment: Yes I globally see what you need but it is a lot specific while I can't help you on precise point without seeing anything

Comment: @Zeratops if you have a server you could move it to, it might work. I'm developing this offline, so I can't provide anything of that sort. I think the main problem is that mousedown/mouseup events override the onclick event.

Comment: I could do this but for now my time is quite reduced since I am in work day ! But I hit you up when I am free :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified like @Zeratops suggested in the comments, with modified code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344111/html5-custom-video-controls/20344487#20344487).

Added a boolean "playbool" that is true if the audio is playing (*play button has been clicked*) and false when the audio is paused (*play button has not been clicked yet, or pause button has been clicked*).

However, clicking on the seek bar (not moving the mouse at all) while audio is playing will not work.

```
$("#html5audio_seek").on("mouseup", function () {
    html5audio.currentTime = $("#html5audio_seek").val();
    if (playbool) {html5audio.play();}
});

$("#html5audio_seek").on("mousedown", function () {
    if (playbool) {html5audio.pause();}
});

html5audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',function (){
    curtime = parseInt(html5audio.currentTime, 10);
    $("#html5audio_seek").attr("value", curtime);
});
```